# Total Generalized Variation

Tags: divergence-operator, total-variation

While reading the paper [Total Generalized Variation](https://imsc.uni-graz.at/mobis/publications/SFB-Report-2009-038.pdf), I came across the following formula (Equation 1.5), which describes the regularization term:

[Total Generalized Variation formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiJLl.png)

While there are a lot of things I don't understand here, my main question is what is the $div^k$ operator. I imagine that it's a generalization of the divergence operator, but how is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper says:

> For the definition of the remaining quantities, we ask for the
>   readers’ patience until Section 2.

Looking there I find $\operatorname{div}^k$ to be defined in equation (2.1) which depends on the definition of $\operatorname{tr}^l$ on page 6.

Thus: Be patient and continue reading.